# Is it possible to trigger AJAX CollapsiblePanelExtender animation from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, collapsiblepanelextender

I am using an AJAX CollapsiblePanelExtender for several sections of a form. I can collapse a panel programatically using the following 2 lines:

```
        ajaxCollapsiblePanelExtender1.Collapsed = true;
        ajaxCollapsiblePanelExtender1.ClientState = "true";
```

However, the expand/collapse animation does not play as when the Expand/CollapseControlID is clicked. It simply appears in the collapsed state. Is it possible to trigger this animation programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open it by clicking the object with javascript/jQuery when you return from the server

I think this may be the only way to get what you want